# How to get TabView .page background style to stick

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-tabview

I have a bunch of TabViews in my view structure all with `.tabViewStyle(.page)` to get paged tab views with the little dots to cycle through some pictures. I want the dots to have a background so they can be seen regardless of the picture contents.

I tried lots of things (labels, tints, foreground colors, background colors, etc.) but nothing worked. I eventually guessed my way into

```
TabView {
    // My Image views
}
.tabViewStyle(.page)
.onAppear {
    UIPageControl.appearance().backgroundStyle = .prominent
}
```

Which does exactly what I want! Until I swipe to the next picture and then the background disappears...

How do I get the backgroundStyle on the TabView to stay?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set the `indexViewStyle` to `always` show

```
TabView {
    // My Image views
}
.tabViewStyle(.page)
..indexViewStyle(.page(backgroundDisplayMode: .always)) <-- HERE
```

Comment: That was it, thanks! How might I find that via the documentation? I don't see how to navigate from TabView to .indexViewStyle (i.e. I don't see how they're connected concepts if I don't already know those terms are specifically connected)